# Linkedin Oauth2 Client Credentials grant type

Tags: linkedin-api, spring-social-linkedin

Asking the question here as the linkedin help forum directed to post things related to API on stackoverflow.

I am developing a feature on our org website to show the top 5 company page feeds setup in linkedin. Ive already setup the required access in developer.linkedin and the whole flow works in the developer.linkedin REST console to fetch the feed.

I am currently recieving this error when i try from my machine to fetch the auth token with a valid client id and secret created.

> https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=OMITTED&client_secret=OMITTED
>
> {
>       "error": "access_denied",
>       "error_description": "This application is not allowed to create application tokens" }

The documentation also mentions that this flow isn't available by default and the users will need to contact linkedin.

> https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v2/oauth2-client-credentials-flow

*"By default, your application will not have the ability to use LinkedIn's client credentials flow.  Contact us to have your application granted permission to use this flow."*

What would be the next steps in requesting access to this flow for my org?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As outlined here:

> By default, your application will not have the ability to use LinkedIn's client credentials flow.  Contact us to have your application granted permission to use this flow.

The next step would be to contact them directly or [Apply to become a Partner](https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply)
and if accepted you'll be granted access to additional data outside of the scope of the user authentication flow (which basically means you'll be able to make calls directly from your application to access certain information)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is well explained by API-University, since the creation of an application in order to get the access_token, will solve the communication issue.

Link to the explanation: https://api-university.com/blog/api-usage/how-to-use-the-linkedin-api-and-oauth/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30125860)