# LinkedIn API: Access Denied when getting Access Token

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to request for an access token using the endpoint:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={clientid}&client_secret={clientsecret}
```

The response I get is:

```
{
    "error": "access_denied",
    "error_description": "This application is not allowed to create application tokens"
}
```

I have set the permissions to r_basicprofile and rw_company_admin.

Comment: This should help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49729991/linkedin-oauth2-client-credentials-grant-type

Answer (score -1):

Client Credential Flow (2-legged OAuth):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin/consumer/context:
Contributors
If your application needs to access APIs that are not member specific, use the Client Credential Flow. Your application cannot access these APIs by default. Contact us to have your application granted permission to use this flow.