# access_denied while using linkedin-api

Tags: linkedin-api

Hello linkedin support.

I have created an app on ttps://www.linkedin.com/developers/ site. With ClientID and secret. I use postman with:

This grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: xxxxxxxx
client_secret: yyyyyyyyyy

send this to https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken.

I’ll get:

```
{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"This application is not allowed to create application tokens"}
```

Why? What did I missed?

Michael Schrading

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linkedin Oauth2 Client Credentials grant type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49729991/linkedin-oauth2-client-credentials-grant-type)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access the Application Auth by default, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/getting-access?context=linkedin%2Fcontext#open-permissions-consumer) (note how the "permissions available to all developers" only list Member Auth, and you are using Application Auth).

Also, [this comment on github](https://github.com/nubelaco/linkedin-api-python3-examples/blob/master/linkedin_api_method_2.py#L7) also supports that:

> If you are ...on a paid subscription to LinkedIn Consumer Product